# How to create spring boot cloud maven based application where parent project is not org.springframework.cloud

Tags: spring, maven, spring-cloud

I want to create spring cloud project where parent project is my common project and all other modules depends on this custom parent project and not on "org.springframework.cloud" as parent project .

I do not want to add this in my parent pom

```
    <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>Brixton.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath/>
    <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```

In simple words I do not want to add spring cloud as parent in maven module hierarchy.

If you generate project using spring initializer [Spring Initializer](https://start.spring.io/) then you get

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>demo</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>demo</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.4.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: ..sry, I don't have the time to post a "fine & clean" answer (nor to try it out), but the solution is obviously to copy everything (relevant) from spring-cloud-starter-parent pom to your (parent) pom..

Answer (score 1):

Remove the parent section and bring in Spring Boot dependencies management as a bom.

```
<dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
      <version>1.5.4.RELEASE</version>
      <type>pom</type>
      <scope>import</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Comment: How to give version in decencies which is inherited from parent ?

Answer (score 1):

You have to add `<dependencyManagement>` section in `pom.xml` file. Looks like,

```
<dependencyManagement>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
        <version>Dalston.SR1</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```